# running and debugging play project from intellij using gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, playframework-2.0

Can you explain of to run and debug a play project from intellij using gradle
with scala?

(The simplest solution of hello world).

Thanks

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.3.0-RC1/firstapp

Comment: but I've asked for scala-gradle solution

Comment: @roman, did you find a way to run it finally?